# Google Compute Engine autoscale based on 'used' memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm looking to scale my Compute Engine instances based on memory which is an agent metric in Stackdriver. The caveat is that out of the 5 states that the agent can monitor(buffered, cached, free, slab, used) [see the link here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-memory), I only want to look at 'used' memory and if that value is above certain %age threshold across the group(or per-instance would also work for me), I want to autoscale.

I've already installed the Stackdriver Monitoring agent in all the nodes across the Managed Instance Group and I am successfully able to visualize 'used' memory in my monitoring dashboard as I'm well acquainted with it.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't do it for autoscaling. This is what I see when I go to configure it in the autoscaling section of MIG.

[image]

In my belief, adding filter expressions should work as expected, since this expression works correctly in the Stackdriver console using the Monitoring dashboard. Also, it's mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#per_instance_filter_requirements) that the syntax is compatible with Cloud Monitoring filter syntax that is given [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters).

I've tried different combinations for the syntax in the filter expression field but none of them has worked. Please help.

Comment: Your metric identifier is already indicate percent memory used, wouldn't it be redundant by putting the same thing in additional filter?

Comment: @WilfredL., Stackdriver can monitor 5 stages of memory(buffered, cached, free, slab and used). See link here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-memory. I only want to autoscale based on what's being 'used'.

Comment: I tried to replicate and got the same issue, but in the document for autoscaling it never mention it can be fine tune in such a way. You might need to open a public issue tracer [1] with Google so they can better work with this. [1] https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: Okay, in that case I don't really understand what the filter expression is for.

Comment: The only syntax I've been able to use that passes the UI validation is `metric.label.state="used"`.  However when I do this, I get an error afterwards saying "Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics.".  So if you're not using a regional instance-group, it may just work for you're use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I was attempting the exact same configuration in attempts to scale based on memory usage.  After testing various unsuccessful entries I reached out to Google support.  Based on your question I can't tell what kind of instance group you have.  It matters because of the following.

#### TLDR

Based on input from Google support, only zonal instance groups allow the filter expression entry.

#### Zonal Instance Group

Only zonal instance groups will allow the metric setting.  The setting you are attempting to enter is correct with `metric.state=used` for a zonal instance group.  However, that field must be left blank for regional instance group.

#### Regional Instance Group

As noted above, applying the filter for a regional instance group is not supported.  As noted in [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics) they mention that you leave that field blank.

> 10. In the Additional filter expression section:
>     For a zonal MIG, optionally enter a filter to use individual values from metrics with multiple streams or labels. For more information, see Filtering per-instance metrics.
>     For a regional MIG, leave this section blank.

If you add an entry you'll receive the message *"Regional managed instance groups do not support autoscaling using per-group metrics."* when attempting to save your changes.

On the other hand if you leave the field empty it will save.  However, I found that leaving the field empty and setting almost any number in the **Target Utilization** field always caused my group to scale to the maximum number.

#### Summary

Google informed me that they do have a feature request for this.  I communicated that it didn't make sense to even have the option to select `percent_used` if it's not supported.  The response was that we should see the documentation updated in the future to clarify that point.